# Print None object properties as empty string

Tags: python, jinja2

I am passing an object to my Jinja2 template to be used as form values.

If a property doesn't exist, it is printing `None` as a string, where I would like it to just print an empty string (aka, nothing).

As there are a lot of properties for the object, I wish to avoid string coercion at the Controller level.

My current Jinja code looks like:

```
value="{{ my_object.my_property }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to utilize the following, which is not too long:

```
{{ my_object.my_property or '' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{{ my_object.my_property if my_object.my_property != None }}
```